# Jenkins input step "Abort" button change label

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

As the title says I am searching for a way to change the label of the "Abort" button on the input step in the scripted Pipeline. I know there is the ability to change the "Proceed" button with

```
input message: "Yes/No?", ok: "Yes"
```

But I can't find a way to change the other Button.

Another question would be if there is a way to add a third or even more buttons to the input step.

Thanks already for all your answers :)

Comment: There's [an issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-51490) in Jenkins's tracker, which you can vote on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually not supported by the "pipeline-input-step-plugin" plugin.

The value of Abort is hard-coded into the code in comparison to the value of "Proceed" which is taken by the "Ok" parameter.

Source: https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-input-step-plugin/search?q=Abort&unscoped_q=Abort

Your options seem to be limited. You can either make a feature request and wait, or fork the repo and make the enhancement yourself by following the design of the "Ok" parameter. This will risk the ease of upgradability as you may encounter conflicts/bugs as maintain your enhancement over newer versions of the plugin unless you send a merge request that they merge.

Also, there is no option for more than those two buttons. You could alternatively have more than one input step for the purpose of additional buttons or you could consider parameterizing your job instead of using input steps. Really depends on your use case.

Comment: is this answer still valid ? I'm not sure if there have been any new feature updates regarding this issue

Comment: Someone opened [a pull request](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-input-step-plugin/pull/32) that adds support for this exact feature, but the author had no time to finish. Pretty much all the work is done, and it's just [waiting to be reopened](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-input-step-plugin/pull/32#issuecomment-675071896).